# Former resident alien now back to home country; Received 1099K, No need to pay US income tax?

Tags: income-tax, form-1099

Situation a bit complicated.

Used to work in the US until June 2018. Continued to sell on eBay and Amazon and received 1099K form in 2019.

Do I still have to file income tax for 2019?

Comment: Go to page 7 on https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040nr.pdf to see whether you must file.